# Difference between Data Mining algorithms and methods

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I read a lot of times in literature that there are several Data Mining methods (for example: decision trees, k-nearest neighbour, SVM, Bayes Classification) and the same for Data Mining algorithms (k-nearest neighbour algorithm, Naive Bayes Algorithm).

Is a DM method using different DM algorithms or is it the same?

An example to clarify - is there any difference between the below?

> I'm using the Naive Bayes classification method.
>   I'm using the Naive Bayes classification algorithm.

Or is "Bayes" the method and "Naive Bayes" the algorithm?

Comment: Those two are just names for the same thing.

Comment: But for example there are various types of algorithms (e.g. C.4.5) for Decision tree methods or not?

Comment: yes, there are different types of decision trees.

Comment: Is dicision tree the method and the C.45 the algorithm?

Comment: This question only makes sense if you can provide a clear definition of `algorithm` and `method`. I myself use these two interchangeably, so I would say no. Others may argue differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot so far: is there maybe someone else with another meaning?